# C++ compiler/SDK for Ubuntu 12.04 - Netbeans

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, netbeans, sdk

I have installed Netbeans 7.1 on Ubuntu. When I was activating C++ in netbeans, it didn't lead me to the page where C++ compiler/SDK exists, as it did in windows.  I am using Cygwin in windows, but seems like it is not there for Linux.

Please guide me to the correct location where I can find correct C++ compiler/SDK for Linux, which I can use in Netbeans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install gcc

gcc is the gnu c and c++ compiler

simply open a console and type:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

CPP setup instructions for netbeans:
http://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I typed that in console, and some process happened, but still netbeans cannot get it. Why?

Comment: Maybe you also need to install the debugger: sudp apt-get install gdb

Im not very Family with Netbeans, so i don't know where you can specify the compiler path etc. But I guess, it must be somewhere in the preferences menu... You can try to install netbeans from the Ubuntu Software Center, maybe this will configure the compiler path automatically ... But im not sure about it, since Netbeans is originally a Java IDE ... Check this: http://netbeans.org/community/releases/69/cpp-setup-instructions.html#verifying

Comment: OK, that worked. Thanks a lot :) However, I find it very easy to install via Ubuntu software center :)